# How to detect which finger touched the mobile screen

Tags: sensor, capacitive, touchscreen

I'm working on a project where I need to detect which finger touched the mobile screen i.e capacitive screen.

I'm not talking about double finger touch or single or drag and move etc. I'm asking which finger i.e middle finger, thumb, little finger, ring finger like this.

This is very helpful in drawing apps like I can draw something from my ring finger and erase from thumb. And I believe some other useful applications were there.

I have no idea on where to start. If anyone can help with any Idea I'm very glad.

Comment: I don't think this is possible at all but filming the hand & analyzing video un direct, but then never a mobile will have enough calculations/CPU performances to do that, I really think it is not possible that way. Second note :  the hardware position of camera (not oriantable) won't permit a good capture  do already two very major problems in the concept you're strting to think about.

Comment: @francoisP I'm looking some kind of sensor which detects the fingers and identify which finger was that. Impossible is too far from me, Somewhere we need to start so I'll take the first step. any idea to start is very much helpfull.

Comment: if I had to do that myself, I would try to use the camera never a sensor or pression differences or temperature differences & so on will be able to do a such specific identification or errors/fauls-positive on identification will be so high the application itself will be no-sense. Imagine an error level about more than 40% of cases....

Comment: @francoisP but in mobile phone selfie camera is on top and it wont cover fingers. That's why I'm thinking on some shape detecting sensors. with your way to detect, camera position need to be adjusted that's one possibility.

Comment: *I'm looking some kind of sensor which detects the fingers and identify which finger was that* Then **think about** if such a sensor existed, how would it be able to identify the fingers? What physical principles would be used? It is easy to ask for a random sensor but that doesn't mean such a sensor is physically possible. Maybe you will need to sense something else and identify the finger from the data that is collected that way.

Comment: It is interesting, but going to be a collection of opinions, I guess. IMO: Register every finger, fingerprint image recognition touch sensor needed. For in case, toe, the tip of the nose, and the tongue.

Comment: BTW, don't the apps have simpler solutions already (I never use apps), like quick double tap, or triple tap, for erase action.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thank you for your information. yes it is complicated, we need to write finger detecting algorithm. but If we can detect a missile coming in sky why can't we detect a finger above the mobile screen. I need to somehow achieve this.

Comment: @jay this is not about mobile app only, I just tried to gave one example of it's usecase that's all. but these seems to be very challenging so I was working on it.

Comment: Detecting missile launch is worth the effort, as much as erasing a drawing.

Comment: @jay I don't know how to explain how this might be helpful in future. But I believe this can be used in various application where we can study animal behaviour too. but as you said from toe to nose I need to detect which object is above the screen and it takes lot of coding.

Comment: @VikasAcharya, my apologies, I was just up voting for you brought a creative subject. Please ignore my comments. I didn't think you would take it serious.

Comment: @francoisP, *filming the hand & analyzing video un direct, but then never a mobile will have enough calculations/CPU performances to do that* You're kidding :-) Modern mobiles have plenty of capacity to do that. Try the image decorating mode on a Google Duo call, for example. That analyses a face to put on cartoon graphics onto a head and body that move in real time, and the budget phones keeps up fine.

Comment: @TonyM you're right I forgoten that  - but forgot the camera disposition, it just cannot film the hand, the face is far enough to be filmed, but not the hand :)

Comment: There are fingerprints sensors. Not on a screen though. Of course you will first need to program the recognized fingerprints.

Comment: @EugeneSh. and then use the same bit of the finger - I don't know about you but I use the pad for fingerprint sensors and the very tip of the finger  for fine drawing.  Simple drag and drop or anything using my thumb depends how I'm holding the phone

Comment: Different people have different shapes and different pressures applied on different fingers. Good luck researching on that with AI or ML. And whether all this research is worth its application is another question.

Comment: how about a wrist band that picks up the nerve impulses which are generated by the fingertip touches ... screen position of each finger could be determined by correlating the timing between the touch detection and resulting nerve impulse ... just a thought ... i have absolutely no idea if nerve impulses from each finger can be differentiated reliably

Comment: Simply put, a capacitive touchscreen on a typical phone (as of now) does not have enough information to make the distinction IMHO. Think about it from the screens perspective. But here's a thought, have the camera look at your face, and based on your facial expressions : draw, erase, etc.

Comment: I really doubt this is possible on a standard touch screen with no other hardware. However combining it with a camera (probably an IR camera, or a depth camera) pointed at the screen could probably work. Another option is to have a (very light) harness/glove on your hand to detect which fingers are extended. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gesture_recognition for ideas. See also the now defunct Leap Motion.

Comment: See also https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220877412_Detecting_and_leveraging_finger_orientation_for_interaction_with_direct-touch_surfaces and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_tracking

Comment: @jcaron cool, right now I'm thinking of using UV sensor, Once I fail Then i'll think on the alternative approach you gave.

Comment: @jsotola That's really a great area to explore. As u said may be nerve impulse are different for each action. we can calculate it and accordingly we can detect fingers I guess. thank you for idea you shared

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this with off-the-shelf hardware this will be difficult. Standard cell phones are not designed for this so you cannot use any of the existing sensors directly.

You may be able to leverage second order effects. You can collect large data bases of touch events with different fingers/people/devices etc. and then record duration, location, vibration, orientation, touch area over time, etc. Then throw a neutral network or suitable machine learning algorithm at it and see if can "learn" to distinguish the different fingers.

This is based on the  hypothesis that different fingers generate different "fingerprints" (pun intended!) in the senor patterns and that a machine learning algorithm can actually correlate and latch on to. Example: you will have different wrist positions if you use your ring finger and maybe that's detectable in the gyro or accelerometer data.

IMO that's a long shot and will require significant amount of work, but I don't see any better alternative at the moment.

Comment: I believe the important point here is “and see **if** it can…”. The thumb can probably be differentiated in most cases. For the others…